# Stream events from server using websockets

Tags: apache-spark, websocket, spark-streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am looking to stream events using web sockets from the server which has an address starting with:

**wss://example.de/Outbound/OutboundInterface**

I am looking for the options where I can stream the events from the server using technologies like Apache spark, Apache flink.

I am unsure as to how do I stream the events into my backend project for the university.

Any pointers will be helpful indicating how do I proceed with the problem statement.

Comment: This question looks awfully similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/39872004/794749

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this is to write a little wrapper that bridges between the websocket interface and standard TCP sockets (which Apache Spark and Apache Flink both support). Here's an example in python that connects to the wikipedia websocket service and prints out the stream of edits:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# sudo pip install socketIO_client==0.5.6
# ./simple.py 2> /dev/null | nc -lk 9999

import socketIO_client
import json

class WikiNamespace(socketIO_client.BaseNamespace):
    def on_change(self, change):
        print(json.dumps(change))

    def on_connect(self):
        self.emit('subscribe', 'en.wikipedia.org')

socketIO = socketIO_client.SocketIO('stream.wikimedia.org', 80)
socketIO.define(WikiNamespace, '/rc')

while True:
    socketIO.wait(10)
```

You can then pipe this through nc to turn this into a socket that Flink, etal can connect to (here I've redirected the errors to /dev/null -- you might rather put them in a file):

```
./simple.py 2> /dev/null | nc -lk 9999
```